# Why the graph gets shifted up here?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to add a translucent vertical red divider with equation x+y-30 to the below graph. It should cut the curve into two sections.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            xtick = {0,20,...,100},
            ytick = {0,20,...,60},
            ztick = {0,40,...,120},
            xlabel = $U_A$, ylabel = $U_B$, zlabel = $S$,
            zlabel style={rotate=-90},
            ticklabel style = {font = \scriptsize},
            colormap/cool
            ]
            \addplot3[name path=toppath, domain=0:30, fill=blue, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4,samples=30] (x,30-x,120);
            \addplot3[name path=botpath, domain=0:30, fill=blue, opacity=0.1, fill opacity=0.4,samples=30] (x,30-x,0);
            \addplot [red] fill between[of=toppath and botpath];
            \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=0:100, domain y=0:60, samples=56]
            { ln((100!/(x!*(100-x)!))*(60!/(y!*(60-y)!))) };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I run the code, I got this odd result

[image]

I don't understand why the original curve gets shifted upwards.

This is what I want to see

[image]

(Also, I wonder what is the best way to change view. I want to look the graph from the perspective of the left corner of the viewing box.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this kind of overlay is not yet available in `pgfplots`. The only solution is to plot different parts of the surface separately, and in this case of the intersecting plane, in the right order so that they overlap correctly. To plot a function on a non-rectangular domain, it is necessary to parametrize the domain that you want to use. In this case, looking from above, we will have a triangle and a polygon.

[image]

Parametrizing triangles given their vertices is simple, but for polygons it can be complicated. I think the simplest solution is to divide the polygon into additional triangles.
[image]

To parameterize a triangle, given three vertices [image: p1], [image: p2] and [image: p3], you can use the following parametrization:

[image: eq1]

[image: eq2]

Obtained the values, we can now plot all the surfaces to get the complete one. Also, it is necessary to set a high sampling rate, otherwise, irregularities at the edges due to low-quality rendering will cause gaps between the junctions of the partial surfaces. This is a very demanding solution, so below there is the code and the resulting graph using `shell-escape` option with `gnuplot` too.

Using only `pgfplots`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            xtick = {0,20,...,100},
            ytick = {0,20,...,60},
            ztick = {0,40,...,120},
            xlabel = $U_A$, ylabel = $U_B$, zlabel = $S$,
            zlabel style={rotate=-90},
            ticklabel style = {font = \scriptsize},
            colormap/cool,
            variable=s,
            variable y=t,
            domain=0:1,
            view/h=15,
            ]   
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, samples=80, samples y=80] ({100-100*s},{-30*s-30*t*s+60},{ ln((100!/(x!*(100-x)!))*(60!/(y!*(60-y)!))) }); %B
                         
\addplot3 [surf,shader=interp, samples=30, samples y=30,] ({100*t*s+30-30*s},{30*s+30*t*s},{ ln((100!/(x!*(100-x)!))*(60!/(y!*(60-y)!))) }); %C
                      
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, samples=30, samples y=30,] ({100+70*t*s-70*s},{60*t*s},{ ln((100!/(x!*(100-x)!))*(60!/(y!*(60-y)!))) }); %D
             
\addplot3 [patch, fill=red, patch type=rectangle] coordinates {(0,30,120) (30,0,120)  (30,0,0) (0,30,0)};
                        
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, samples=30, samples y=30] ({30-30*s},{30*s*t},{  ln((100!/(x!*(100-x)!))*(60!/(y!*(60-y)!))) }); %A
                          
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `pgfplots` and `gnuplot` :

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, convert={true}]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
            xtick = {0,20,...,100},
            ytick = {0,20,...,60},
            ztick = {0,40,...,120},
            xlabel = $U_A$, ylabel = $U_B$, zlabel = $S$,
            zlabel style={rotate=-90},
            ticklabel style = {font = \scriptsize},
            colormap/cool,
            view/h=15,
            ]   
            
           \addplot3[surf, shader=interp, thick ]  gnuplot [ raw gnuplot, id=B ]  {
           set samples 60,60; 
           set isosamples 60,60;
           set parametric; 
           fx(u,v)=100-100*u; 
           fy(u,v)=-30*u-30*v*u+60; 
           fz(u,v)= log((100!/((int((100-100*u)))!*(100-int((100-100*u)))!))*(60!/((int((-30*u-30*v*u+60)))!*(60-int((-30*u-30*v*u+60)))!)));
           splot [0:1][0:1] fx(u,v), fy(u,v), fz(u,v)}; %B
           
            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp]  gnuplot [ raw gnuplot, id=C]  {
           set samples 60,60; 
           set isosamples 60,60;
           set parametric;
           gx(u,v)=100*v*u+30-30*u; 
           gy(u,v)=30*u+30*v*u; 
           gz(u,v)= log((100!/((int(100*v*u+30-30*u))!*(100-int(100*v*u+30-30*u))!))*(60!/((int(30*u+30*v*u))!*(60-int(30*u+30*v*u))!)));
           splot [0:1][0:1] gx(u,v), gy(u,v), gz(u,v) }; %C
           
           \addplot3[surf, shader=interp]  gnuplot [ raw gnuplot, id=D]  {
    set samples 60,60; 
    set isosamples 60,60;
           set parametric;
           hx(u,v)=100+70*v*u-70*u; 
           hy(u,v)= 60*v*u; 
           hz(u,v)=log((100!/((int(100+70*v*u-70*u))!*(100-int(100+70*v*u-70*u))!))*(60!/((int(60*v*u))!*(60-int(60*v*u))!)));
           splot [0:1][0:1] hx(u,v), hy(u,v), hz(u,v) }; %D

                        \addplot3 [patch, fill=red, patch type=rectangle] coordinates {(0,30,120) (30,0,120)  (30,0,0) (0,30,0)};
                        
                        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp]  gnuplot [raw gnuplot, id=A ]  {
                        set samples 60,60; 
                        set isosamples 60,60;
                        set parametric; 
                        splot [0:1][0:1] 30-30*u,30*u*v,log((100!/((int(30-30*u))!*(100-int(30-30*u))!))*(60!/((int(30*u*v))!*(60-int(30*u*v))!)))   }; %A
            
             
       \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

To change the view, you can use the `view/h= angle` option, remembering to adjust the order of the surfaces accordingly to achieve the correct overlap.

There are some differences in the rendering of the two methods. I haven't been able to achieve better results, but feel free to adjust the sampling to see if you can find a better combination.

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks more complicated than I thought!